# pagination does not work with query_posts. Help!

Tags: pages, customization, query-posts, pagination, homepage

I made ​​a separate page template (added sidebar), this page contains all the posts. Pagination works!
But, if this page set as the home page, pagination is not working!
Please help find solutions myself I can not ...

This my code
[This code of my custom posts page](http://pastebin.com/LNnhAa4V)

[This code of my pagination](http://pastebin.com/mSxBKP4U)

Comment: Never use `query_posts. Very likely that's what breaks the pagination. Use `WP_Query` instead. [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: Please, research this Stack, [there are plenty of similar questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bpagination+is%3Aquestion). Take a look at this site [faq] and try to put all necessary code in the Question itself, you are free to [edit] it whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php query_posts( array(
 'posts_per_page' => 15,
 'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),
));
?>
```

It worked for me. You can change the `posts_per_page` numbers according to whatever you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, it also does not solve the problem :( it works if you do not set the page as the home page.